# Message notification when inside another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I'm carrating on an app that was written by a programmer before me. It has only 2 view controllers: the main one displaying chat (its the root view controller) and a second one to tinker with your profile. I was asked to implement some kind of notification (preferably one that pops up at the top of the screen) to the user that a message has arrived when they are inside that profile-tinkering view controller. Must I use the APNS server technique, or can I use an easier technique by utilizing the App Delegate somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `APNS`, I prefer the local notification,`didReceiveLocalnotification` method will get called,then display an alert
2. Use delegate,assign delegate to the profile controller,and implement the required method,when you have a message arrived,display an alert

Answer (score 1):

When you are inside another view, the `APNS` wont get displayed because the application is already in foreground.

When app is in foreground and you receive an `APNS`, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method will get called.

You can read `APNS` package here and notify user of this in a way you want, for e.g. you can display an alert.